# my login/index zul page is loading twice, where as i am only calling it once

Tags: java, zk

I am using zk ce version 6.5 and i have a problem. My login/index pages is being loaded twice.

1. when i on logout button call this:

   Executions.createComponents("login", center, null);

above page has two fields and i am using MVVM approach.

Now it loads fine, but as soon as i enter the username in the textbox or enter the password in textbox, page is automatically refreshed. I have checked in my code, i am not calling the above method anywhere else in a process here.

Please tell me why on textbox/password textbox i am getting this behaviour for the loginpage. once it's reloaded twice, it gets the username and takes me to home page. now i logout and same scenario.

for two times, i am getting call to this method, once is obvious, bacause on logout i called it, but on entering any text in textbox and removing the focus from it. then this method is again called.

```
@AfterCompose
public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view){
    Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false);
 }
```

I have inspected my code too, there is no event on any of the textfield.

login.zul

```
<zk>
    <window id="loginWin" border="none" width="100%" height="100%"
        apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vmc') @init('com.example.LoginViewModel')"
        validationMessages="@id('vmsgs')">

        <borderlayout>
            <west border="normal" size="70%" title="What Intelliops Do?">
                <div width="100%" height="100%">
                    asdasd as asd a d asdasd a sd asd asasd asd d asdasd as
                    d a d asdasd a sd asd asasd asd a d asdasd a sd asd
                    asasd asd a d asdasd a sd asd asasd asd
                </div>
            </west>
            <east border="normal" size="30%" title="Login">
                <div width="100%" height="100%">
                    <grid sizedByContent="true"
                        form="@id('lv') @load(vmc.userDto)
                       @save(vmc.userDto, before='loginButtonInvoke')
                       @validator('com.example.LoginValidator')">
                        <columns>
                            <column width="50%"></column>
                            <column width="50%"></column>
                        </columns>
                        <rows>
                            <row align="left" width="100%"
                                style="background:white;.row:hover{background-color: #fff};border:none">
                                <cell style="text-align:right">
                                    User Name
                                </cell>
                                <cell>
                                    <textbox id="userNameTextBox" type="text"
                                        value="@bind(lv.user.username)" maxlength="50" />
                                    <image src="@load(vmsgs['userNameTextBoxError'])" width="12px"
                                        height="12px" tooltiptext="@load(vmsgs['userNameTextBox'])"></image>
                                </cell>
                            </row>
                            <row width="100%"
                                style="background:white;.row:hover{background-color: #fff};border:none">
                                <cell style="text-align:right">
                                    Password
                                </cell>
                                <cell>
                                    <textbox id="passwordTextBox" type="password"
                                        value="@bind(lv.user.password)" maxlength="20" />
                                    <image src="@load(vmsgs['passwordTextBoxError'])" width="12px"
                                        height="12px" tooltiptext="@load(vmsgs['passwordTextBox'])" />
                                </cell>
                            </row>
                            <row width="100%"
                                style="background:white;.row:hover{background-color: #fff};border:none">
                                <cell style="text-align:right">
                                    <button id="loginButton" label="Login"
                                        onClick="@command('loginButtonInvoke')" />
                                </cell>
                                <cell>
                                    <label id="loginErrorLabel" style="color:red" />
                                </cell>
                            </row>
                            <row spans="2" width="100%"
                                style="background:white;.row:hover{background-color: #fff};border:none">
                                <cell colspan="2" style="text-align:right">
                                    <a id="forgetPasswordLink">
                                        Forgot Password?
                                    </a>
                                </cell>
                            </row>
                        </rows>
                    </grid>
                </div>
            </east>
        </borderlayout>
    </window>
</zk>
```

loginviewmode class

```
package com.example;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.AfterCompose;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextType;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.Selectors;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.Wire;
import org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.SpringUtil;
import org.zkoss.zul.Label;
import org.zkoss.zul.Textbox;

import com.example.UserDTO;
import com.example.IUserService;
import example.Pages;
import example.TemplateUtil;
import example.UserUtil;

public class LoginViewModel{

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    IUserService userService = (IUserService)SpringUtil.getBean("userService");

    UserDTO userDto = new UserDTO();

    private static final String USER_ROLES = "userRoles";
    private static final String MASTER = "master";

    @Wire("#userNameTextBox")
    Textbox userNameTextBox;

    @Wire("#passwordTextBox")
    Textbox passwordTextBox;

    @Wire("#loginErrorLabel")
    Label loginErrorLabel;

    @AfterCompose
    public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view){
        Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false);
     }

    @Command("loginButtonInvoke")
    public void loginButtonInvoke(){
        logger.info("LoginViewModel:afterCompose >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        logger.info("loginButtonInvoke: " + userDto.getUserIntelliOps().getUsername() + " " + userDto.getUserIntelliOps().getPassword());
        userDto = userService.getUserAuthentication(userDto);



        if(userDto!=null){
            UserUtil.setSession(userDto);
            logger.info("loginButtonInvoke:userDto!=null ");
            /*List<ViewObjectOperation> list = userService.getAllOtherOperationsService().userAuthorizationMatrix(userDto.getUserIntelliOps().getRoles().get(0).toString());*/
            //List<ViewObjectOperation> list = userService.getAllOtherOperationsService().userAuthorizationMatrix(3+"");
            //logger.info("asdasdas   " + list.size());
            /*getUserAuthorizedMenu*/
            //TODO what is the following line doing here????
            userService.getUserAuthorizedMenu();

            TemplateUtil.loadContent(Pages.HOME_FILE,true);
        }else{
            if(userDto==null){
                userDto = new UserDTO();
            }
        loginErrorLabel.setValue("Invalid username or password.");
        }

    }

    public UserDTO getUserDto() {
        return userDto;
    }

    public void setUserDto(UserDTO userDto) {
        this.userDto = userDto;
    }




}
```

TemplateUtil class to draw the pages

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Path;
import org.zkoss.zul.A;
import org.zkoss.zul.Borderlayout;
import org.zkoss.zul.Button;
import org.zkoss.zul.Center;
import org.zkoss.zul.Include;
import org.zkoss.zul.North;


public class TemplateUtil {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TemplateUtil.class.getName());

    public static void loadContent(String contentPage, boolean isMenu) {


        logger.info("TemplateUtil: loadContent().......... ");

        Borderlayout mainlayout = (Borderlayout) Path.getComponent("/main/mainLayout");
        North topHeader = mainlayout.getNorth();

        topHeader.getFellow("menuDiv").setVisible(isMenu);

        //TODO remove the following logger

        if(isMenu==true ){
            anchorUsername.setLabel(UserUtil.getUserName());
            logger.info("isMenu==true....");
            Executions.createComponents(Pages.MENU_FILE, topHeader.getFellow("menuDiv"), null);
            UserUtil.setSession(true);
        }

        topHeader.invalidate();

        Center center = mainlayout.getCenter();
        center.getChildren().clear();
        logger.info("contentPage: " + contentPage);
        Executions.createComponents(contentPage, center, null);

    }


}
```

please help me on this

Let me update you. 1. first time no refresh 2. after login, when i click on logout and go to login page, as soon as i add the value in any of the textbox, pages refreshes. no action is written on any of those fields.

Comment: Hi Vicky, if you can provide a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) you'll likely get a solution from the community quickly.

Comment: Click the link. It's a 'best practice' for posting questions on StackOverflow. If you can provide the community a self contained working example you are going to get better help from others. Aside from making it easy for others to recreate and debug the problem, it's also a courtesy that is appreciated; people like to see a well posed question and will be more apt to take the time to help.

Comment: @Seab Connolly added SSCE

Comment: Hi Vicky, that helps but is not an SSCE; it's just your code. You reference classes not included like `UserUtil`. I can't recreate the problem to be able to help well, but try removing the `@bind`s from the textboxes and see if your problem goes away. If it does, that'll give you a clue where your bug lies.

Comment: sorry but i can't share all the files because of some reasons but let me tell you, i am just mainting a session in UserUtil. However I am using mvvm as you can see and without bind i can't populate the values in my binding object. i am still getting the same result. Let me update you. 1. first time no refresh 2. after login, when i click on logout and go to login page, as soon as i add the value in any of the textbox, pages refreshes. no action is written on any of those feilds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to understand why you are doing ...

```
Executions.createComponents("login", center, null);
```

When you going for **logout**

From my understanding you can do this thing like this...

```
//Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().invalidate();//Condition base if you needed use it otherwise dont use it
Executions.getCurrent().getSession().invalidate();
Executions.sendRedirect("/login.zul");
```

Comment: because i have a template, in which i am embedding login.zul, that's why i am creating it.

Comment: i will definitely try your code and will let you know how it goes

Comment: i tried that on logout, it's seems better, i did test for 5 minutes, where after changing the value of username, only once auto page refresh was done but there is some 10 pixcel red lines of like 200 pixel width apear at top center part of the page on logout, in case of debug mode, i don't see any such thing. any idea about that ?

Comment: Its not relates with my answer you are doing something wrong thats why you are getting this issue ..I am using above code in my application i did not saw any such thing

Comment: problem was in code, "Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().invalidate();" which was causing issue, i noticed it was some kind of zk message which slides in and in a eye blink disappear. but without the desktop line, my refresh issue is resolved. trick is to redirect to the page on logout. thanks and please remove the desktop invalidate from answer. thanks a lot.