# zk: after confirmation box, page refresh issue, binder not working

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I was successfully deleting selected items from listbox and after that all objects were deleted from db and listbox was refreshed.
then i added the confirmation box with yes and no option, then my list wasn't refreshed. i saw this thread with similar problem on zk forum with a solution, i implemented it but getting the class cast exception

I am using MVVM

http://forum.zkoss.org/question/73640/refreshing-listbox-after-deleting-an-itemrow/

code getting the exception:

```
AnnotateDataBinder binder = (AnnotateDataBinder) userWin.getAttribute("binder");
                    binder.loadAll();
```

exception:

```
Mar 21, 2013 5:22:23 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl handleError:1352
SEVERE: >>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.zkoss.bind.AnnotateBinder cannot be cast to org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinder
```

looking forward to hear from you. I have searched the net, but couldn't find anything but updating the zk. i am already using the latest version of zk 6.5.1.1.

thanks in advance.

@after adding your suggested line of code, my list was not updated, here is my method

```
 @Override
    @Command("deleteAllSelected")
    @NotifyChange({"selectedObject","objectList"})
    public void deleteAllSelected() {
        logger.info("in deleteAllSelected()>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

        logger.info("direct selection: " + objectList.getSelection());
        final Set<UserIntelliopsDTO> setMe = objectList.getSelection();
        logger.info("selectedion size in dellete all" + setMe.size());



        EventListener<ClickEvent> clickListener = new EventListener<Messagebox.ClickEvent>() {
            public void onEvent(ClickEvent event) throws Exception {
                if (Messagebox.Button.YES.equals(event.getButton())) {
                    int i =0;
                    for(UserIntelliopsDTO dto:setMe){

                        userService.deleteUserIntelliops(dto.getUserIntelliOps().getUserId());

                        logger.info("siapa:userIntelliops " + dto.getUserIntelliOps() +  dto.getUserIntelliOps().getUserId());
                        selectedObject = null;

                        logger.info("iteration: " + i);
                        ++i;
                    }

                    selectedObject = null;
                    deleteAllSelectedButton.setVisible(false);
                    enableEditMode(true);


                }
            }
        };
        Messagebox.show("Are you sure you want to delete all selected records?", "Delete All Selected",
                new Messagebox.Button[] { Messagebox.Button.YES,
                        Messagebox.Button.NO }, Messagebox.QUESTION,
                clickListener);


        BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, this, "*");

    }
```

Comment: Are you usng MVC or MVVM Architecture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are using MVVM Model..So you can do this thing when you will click on delete button below method will code...

```
 @Command
public void doDeleteItems(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
        logger.debug("Delete Icon selected");

if (myModel.getSelectedListItem() == null || myModel.getSelectedListItem().isEmpty()) {
            showError("No rows are selected");
        } else {

Messagebox.show("Are you sure you want to delete?", "Alert !!", Messagebox.YES | Messagebox.NO, Messagebox.QUESTION,new org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener() {

public void onEvent(Event evt) throws InterruptedException {
    if (evt.getName().equals("onYes")) {
//Add code for Deletion
  if (listModel.contains(deletedObj))
listModel.remove(deletedObj); 
}
else{
//Do somthing else
}
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, this, "*");//this means current viewmodel object and refresh the variables
```

}

As i did `BindUtils.postNotifyChange()` it will do magic for you  refreshing the list or you can use  `NotifyChange("*")`

One more thing you have to do here remove object from list after deleting the record...

Comment: i have followed it and not working for me. i have attached my method above. thanks

Comment: answer edited as i saw u did not deleted the object from list thats why it is showing in list

Comment: HI, I did tried that too , but still after removing the object from the list, it wasn't working, I am using Executions.createComponents() method to redirect to current page, to fix the issue.

Comment: an you use BindUtils.postNotifyChange() for your listbox and remove NotifyChange i am sure you are doing something wrong

Comment: may be and i agree with you, i will look into it later, but for the time being i am working on different module due to timelines.

Comment: as i don't have time but you had put a serious effort and i am sure, the solution will work if i give it little time. so i am accepting the answer and thanks for timely response. can you please look into this issue, i will be really greatful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269086/my-login-index-zul-page-is-loading-twice-where-as-i-am-only-calling-it-once

Comment: please check question answered.

Comment: It works for me, but only with the correct this-Object. Define `Object thisVM = this;` before the `Messagebox.show()` call and use `thisVM` instead of `this` on the `postNotifyChange` call.

Comment: Hmm.May be because you intialized thisVM object from this object

Comment: Yes, that's the point. The code in your answer did not work for me, because "this" refers to the inner EventHandler class, not the outer view-model class. With the mentioned JavaScript-style "self" object, it works.

Comment: What if we are not using ViewModel? How can we use `BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, this, "*");` inside a composer?

Comment: Simple in your method