# ZK refresh binding value inside Composer

Tags: java, zk

I have an object binded in zul page and inside zul page user may edit value of this object by pressing edit button. When user click the edit button the value of the object is changing inside composer (and also the value of the object changes in database). Then, it returns to the same zul page.But the value of binded element is not changed inside zul. Only if i refresh the page i can see the change. How can i change the value of the binded element without refreshing page or maybe by refresing zk window inside zul? As far as i understand there is way by using ModelBinding ( [zk: after confirmation box, page refresh issue, binder not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15547642) ) In my case there is not ModelBinding, I have to do inside Composer when user click edit button.

```
public class EditUserDetailsComposer extends GenericForwardComposer<Component>{
    protected Window userDetailWin;
    private Person selectedUser;
    protected Textbox name;

     public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
            super.doAfterCompose(comp);
            comp.setAttribute("userDetailController", this, true);
            //...
     }

    public void onClick$edit(){
           this.selectedUser.setName(name.getValue());
           //...
           userOper.update(selectedUser);//change db value
    }
    public Person getSelectedUser(){
        return this.selectedUser;
    }
    //...
 }
```

And inside zul page:

```
 <zk  xmlns:c="client" xmlns:x="xhtml">
   <?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" root="./userDetailWin"?>
   <window  id="userDetailWin" apply="project.component.EditUserDetailsComposer " >
    ........

     <div class="widget-body">
    <div class="widget-main">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">User Name</div>

        <div class="col-sm-reset">
        <textbox value = "@{userDetailController.selectedUser.name}" id="name"/>
        </div>
     </div>
    <separator></separator>
      </div>
   </div>
    ......
    <button class="btn btn-primary" label="Edit" id="edit"/>
```

....

Comment: On wich zk version do you ran your system? Cos `GenericForwardComposer` is outdated and `SelectorComposer` is the way to go now. And pleas post your zul as well.

Comment: Thank you for your information.I'm using ZK 7.

Comment: As you explain, `this.selectedUser.setName(name.getValue());` sets the right name to the user, which implies, that the vale of the textbox must be the new one. Is there a different textbox or label with the wrong value? Keep in mind, that a expression like this `value = "@{userDetailController.selectedUser.name}"` is not a dynamic binding, but a "load once" command.